# How is kiwase Uke done?

Tags: karate, sparring

I would like to know how kiwase uke is done in Seido Karate? I know its a type of block but I would like preferably a video example.

Comment: Can I double-check exactly what block you're looking for? The [Seido Karate syllabus](http://www.seidokarate.co.nz/Syllabus.pdf) doesn't list 'kiwase uke'. Could it be 'Kakiwake uke' you're after?